# Differences between v3 and v2 of YouTube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm doing some new work using the YouTube API.  I know there are two versions, v2 and v3, but I can't find the differences anywhere.  What are the differences?

I know v3 is labeled "experimental".  But:

- What's better about it?
- Other than being experimental, what's worse about it?
- Will v2 be phased out?
- For new dev work, should I use v2 or v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some answers (in my opinion ..)

What's better about it?

- Search videos, channels and playlists using freebase topics

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search

- Retrieve activities

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities

Other than being experimental, what's worse about it?

- Changes in API calls that you use in your app

For new dev work, should I use v2 or v3

- I think the answer depends on what your application should do and the type of application

Comment: Additional v2/v3 discussion over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527815/youtube-api-difference-between-api-key-and-developer-key