# Youtube v2 vs v3 and requires api registering

Tags: youtube-api, version, registration

I'm looking at to both versions of youtube api v2 and v3. So I noticed v3 requires app registration to use it and v2 doesn't. Is it true?

If doesn't can I use v3 without any app-register?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these answers on youtube v2 deprecation faq and stackoverflow:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/deprecation_faq#anonymity

[Differences between v3 and v2 of YouTube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224311/differences-between-v3-and-v2-of-youtube-api)